# Not really sure what to do with the checkin tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Under the [checkin](/questions/tagged/checkin), there are two main uses

- Revision control check in
- Location check in

Which would work? Or should the tag be scrapped altogether?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of revision control, a tag for the specific revision control system would do. The same thing goes for Facebook's location check in.

In either case, looking at the questions tagged, I don't really see a clear winner in terms of use. Nor is there a particular descriptiveness in using the tag that would not be apparent from the question title, combined with an appropriate technology/system tag.

I think it can be safely scrapped.